# How to create a external directory using scoped storage and give access to the directory android

Tags: android, firebase, file, android-10.0, scoped-storage

In my app i need to create an external directory and store document files to it in sub directories. Upto Android Pie, API 28 it is going well. From Android 10 it has changed and in scoped storage how can i create a directory in external storage and give permission to that entire directory? I want to download files using uri to those directories and i want to read them later using their uri.